# MySQL order by date and integer within months

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following table:

```
--------------------------------------
  PK       integer          date
--------------------------------------
  1          0             2014/11/14
  2          2             2014/11/01
  3          0             2014/11/25
  4          1             2014/11/01
  5          0             2014/12/25
  6          1             2014/12/01
```

What I want to do is to order by the date column, BUT also an ascending order on the integer column AND to have the November rows before the December rows. So my output should be like this:

```
--------------------------------------
  PK       integer          date
--------------------------------------
  1          0             2014/11/14
  3          0             2014/11/25
  4          1             2014/11/01
  2          2             2014/11/01
  5          0             2014/12/25
  6          1             2014/12/01
```

Comment: 14th goes before 25th, and 25th goes before 1st?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ORDER BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date), integer, DAYOFMONTH(date)
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use

```
ORDER BY YEAR(`date`), MONTH(`date`), `integer`, `date`
```

That should give the ordering you want.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/abd064/2/0